# Leaflet.js: Is a Circle a good way to create a search for an area to create a route?

Tags: leaflet, routing, esri-leaflet, open-source-routing-machine

I am trying to create a route for a user based on a search of an area based on topography data. The criteria is an elevation property.

E.G. a user can search an area and get a route based on elevation.

The start/finish could be highest or lowest in elevation.

Example: if the user wanted to start at the highest elevation, then ever point in the route would be lower in slope or elevation.

ex: `[A, B, C, D, E]`*

The above is a route where the start is `A` and end is `E` .
Traversing the route yields every point being lower in elevation than the last point in the route.

**Obviously this can be used in reverse if you wanted to go uphills!!*

ex: `[E, D, C, B, A]` whew!

I am using the [leaflet-topography library](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-topography) to get the elevation data for a lat/lng point.

What I've done is use some functions to plot the points inside the area of a circle,

I have a center point i.e. the radius. And essentially I plot `n` amount of points on each of the circle's degree.

`[0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270, 255, 240, 225, 210, 195, 180, 165, 150, 135, 120, 105, 90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15],`

Each point gets passed into [esri-leaf-lereverse-geocode](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/reverse-geocode.html) to get an actual address on the map for the routing later.

It looks like this.

While this works, the challenge I'm facing is when creating a route.

I imagine a typical directions/routing solution probably has points for every point on the map, thus creating an easier time for the routing function itself.

So is this a good way to go about getting data for a routing experience?

[image]

Comment: A route to and from where?

Comment: I'm asking is this a good way to create a route using this data.

Comment: I'm confused at to what type of route you want to create

Comment: I'm sorry I added some context.

Comment: Oh, I saw another question about elevation based paths, I think I get it now

Comment: Please don't ask practically the same question twice: [Leaflet JS: How to check if a Lat/Longitude is in proximity going away from the original point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438993/leaflet-js-how-to-check-if-a-lat-longitude-is-in-proximity-going-away-from-the). Decide which one you want to ask and delete the other one.

Comment: @TomazicM If you actually read it you'd see they're different.

Comment: Questions might be different, but both are trying to solve the same problem. And by the way, if you don't care to answer the question in comments to the other question, you can hardly expect help.

Comment: I honestly didn't get the ping from my other question.